# How can i write a Regex for this url below?

Tags: django

`url http://localhost:port/api/text/arabic stemmer algorithm`

i have created one but it take just the first word :
`r'text/(?P<text>\w+)/?'`
i'm using Django framework
i need to select all the text "arabic stemmer algorithm" with white sapaces
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing:

```
url(r'text/(?P<text>[\w ]+)/?')  # allows whitespace
```

or

```
url(r'text/(?P<text>.+?)/?')  # allows all characters before the next slash
```